# Comparing an Arduino DC-DC boost converter with LM2577 modules

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGP_Xmc3tYs)
[image]

with this code:

```
/*
 * This is an example code for a BOOST converter circuit made with arduino + feedback
 * I've used arduino NANO. We have to set the timer of the PWM on pin D3
 * The feedback is connected to A1 and we set the desired voltage with a
 * potnetiometer connected to A0.
 * 
 * Subscribe: http://www.youtube.com/c/electronoobs
 * webpage: http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_circuitos_tut10.php
 */

 
int potentiometer = A0; //The input from the potentiometer is A0
int feedback = A1;      //The feedback input is A1
int PWM = 3;            //Digital pin D3 por PWM signal
int pwm = 0;            //Initial value of PWM width

void setup() {
  pinMode(potentiometer, INPUT);
  pinMode(feedback, INPUT);
  pinMode(PWM, OUTPUT);  
  TCCR2B = TCCR2B & B11111000 | B00000001;    // pin 3 and 11 PWM frequency of 31372.55 Hz
}

void loop() {  
  float voltage = analogRead(potentiometer);    //We read the value of the potentiometer, which is the desired value
  float output  = analogRead(feedback);         //We read the feedback, which is the real value

  //If the desired value is HIGHER than the real value, we increase PWM width
  if (voltage > output)
   {
    pwm = pwm+1;
    pwm = constrain(pwm, 1, 254);
   }
   
  //If the desired value is LOWER than the real value, we decreaase PWM width
  if (voltage < output)
   {
    pwm = pwm-1;
    pwm = constrain(pwm, 1, 254);
   }

   analogWrite(PWM,pwm);  //Finally, we create the PWM signal
}
```

I would like to know about its output quality for powering some IOT modules like ESP8266 by AMS117 regulator and ESP8266, in comparison with commercial [the LM2577 XL6009  DC-DC boost converter](https://www.makerlab-electronics.com/product/dc-dc-boost-converter-lm2577/), output quality for this kind of usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple module based on the LM2577 or XL6009 or (tip) SX1308 will:

1. **just work**. Open some expensive measurement equipment and in some you might find module based DCDC converters. These are expensive! Why are they used anyway? Because these **just work**. Engineers don't want to waste their time on something that can be bought as a ready-to-go module. Those modules are designed by engineers that specialize in DCDC converters so they can be relied upon. The cheap modules form China aren't that good quality but still much better than an Arduino based DCDC converter.
2. be much more robust, if the software in the Arduino craches and the MOSFET is switched on all the time, components will be damaged and best case, the battery will be emptied. The DCDC converter chips do not run software so cannot crash. Also they have overheating and overcurrent protection. The Arduino solution does not.
3. be best if you want low battery power consumption
4. be **much** cheaper.

All in all, I see **no reason whatsoever** to make your own DCDC converter. The only reason to build one is **for educational purposes**, but then be prepared that components might be damaged (use a current limited 5 V supply to prevent that).

Comment: In a case you need some custom voltage for one period of time and then another one, e.g. 12V to trigger relay, and then 3.3V to hold it. I actually didn't find any ready solution module for that on a market